# JQuery. $.get(url, callback) doesn't fire callback

Tags: jquery, ajax

We've migrated IIS-hosted site to another landscape and for some reason $.get functions on our web-pages started not to fire callbacks though I still have "200 OK" result during $.get execution

I guess that something is wrong with server response (encoding, response headers or something) but can't figure out what exactly.

Please, take a look at screenshot I've attached - may be you have some ideas?

[image]

Comment: Please share some code, it's pretty much impossible to say otherwise.

Comment: You appear to have included some non-JSON data in your response (line 2 onwards). Probably jQuery cannot parse the response for that reason. If you're returning JSON from the server you must return **only** JSON